# NEW google spreadsheet importhtml not working

Tags: google-sheets

Converting from old to new google spreadsheet:

old version

=importhtml("www.pgatour.com/tournaments/farmers-insurance-open/results.html";"table";2)

works as advertised as does index 0.

In the New version of spreadsheets

=importhtml("www.pgatour.com/tournaments/farmers-insurance-open/results.html","table",2)

Returns a #N/A with a message of Error: Could not fetch url: www.pgatour.com/tournaments/waste-management-phoenix-open/results.html.

I have also posted thai question on the Google forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
=importhtml("http://www.pgatour.com/tournaments/farmers-insurance-open/results.html";"table";2) :)
```

Exchange `,` to `;` :)

Update 2014-01-10:

Here is my spreadsheet with working this function (and with ";"): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-k7aNQXs9G5Sj3Py042Iw9oncJv6I-FByUBT1rq0gYQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes you right - in my spreadsheet ";" was converted to "," :).

Comment: Adding "//http/" at the front seems to make it work.  An answer in the Google forum suggests that importhttp is one of the functions that dont work yet (SIC!).  I dont seem to be able to make ";" work in my sheets they all are converted to "," as soon as I paste or enter,  even when I copy the text from @jacek2v spreadsheet

Comment: =IMPORTHTML("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_India","table",4) appears to work in new spreadsheets, but other ones don't!

Comment: - it's altered my formating so look here for an example that works https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en